# How do i make the advanced filter copy one row of data to range?

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I need to filter data in column 26. Sometimes after filtering there will only be one row of data. when i use the advanced filter apparently i cant copy one row.

This is my code. i get the error here `.Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(.Rows.count, 26).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, Copytorange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.count), Unique:=True`

```
    With ws


        Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.count, 26).End(xlUp))
        .Columns(.Columns.count).Clear
        .Range(.Cells(2, 26), .Cells(.Rows.count, 26).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, Copytorange:=.Cells(1, .Columns.count), Unique:=True

        For Each rfl In .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.count), .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).End(xlUp))
            vendor = Trim(Left(rfl.Text, 31))
'            MsgBox (vendor)
            If WksExists(vendor) Then
               Sheets(vendor).Cells.Clear
            Else

                Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
                wsNew.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)
                wsNew.Name = Trim(vendor)
            End If

            rData.AutoFilter Field:=26, Criteria1:=vendor & "*"
            rData.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(vendor).Cells(1, 1)
            Worksheets(vendor).Columns.AutoFit
        Next rfl
    End With
    ws.Columns(Columns.count).ClearContents
    rData.AutoFilter
```

is it possible for me to add a condition to check if the used range is 1 row then copy that range in a different way to `rData`?

Comment: You can use `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to count the rows after filtering.

Comment: i do not want it to copy the header row. i just want the row below the header row. is there any way to do that?

Comment: Yes you can, but then you will have to apply the Regular Filter and copy the visible range. Not sure how to do it with Advance Filter.

Comment: With Advanced Filter you'd have to copy the header row and then delete it.